# How does Mathematica decide that Log[2,8] is integer?

Tags: expression-test, binary

At school we learned that $\log_b(x)=\log(x)/\log(b)$, which is implemented in *Mathematica* as `Log[b, x]`, but the results are different.

```
Log[8]/Log[2] // N
```

returns

> ```
> 3.  (* Real *)
> ```

while

```
Log[2, 8]
```

returns

> ```
> 3  (* Integer *)
> ```

If I want to validate the argument of my `hadamardMatrix[]` function as a power of 2:

```
hadamardMatrix[1] := {{1}}
hadamardMatrix[2] := {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}
hadamardMatrix[n_ /; IntegerQ[Log[2, n]]] := 
       KroneckerProduct[hadamardMatrix[2], hadamardMatrix[n/2]]
```

How can I be sure that any `Log[2, 2`<sup>N</sup>`]` will always be regarded as integer?

Comment: Of course, in your first snippet, you ensured your not getting an `Integer` by applying `N`. Try `Log[2, 8]//N` to see that you don't get an `Integer` either.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436464/mathematica-cant-simplifylog4-log2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An interesting question which I've never specifically considered before.

Some observations:

```
Log[8]/Log[2] // FullSimplify

Log2[8]

Log[2, 8]
```

> ```
> 3
>
> 3
>
> 3
> ```

```
And @@ IntegerQ /@ Log2[2^Range[50000]]

And @@ Table[IntegerQ@Log2[2^RandomInteger[5*^8]], {500}]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

*Mathematica* documentation explicitly states:

> `Log2` gives exact integer or rational number results when possible.

Also for `Log`:

> `Log` gives exact rational number results when possible.
>
> For certain special arguments, `Log` automatically evaluates to exact values.

I think that based on the combination of the empirical result and the statements in the documentation that it is safe to assume that `Log2` will return an integer when given a 2^n number.

As far as *how* this is determined the [Implementation Notes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) say only:

> Log and inverse trigonometric functions use Taylor series and functional relations.

which I'm not sure applies.

---

Timings of `Log2` compared to J. M.'s lovely bit-level test:

```
Do[IntegerQ @ Log2 @ n, {n, 1*^7}] // AbsoluteTiming // First

Do[BitAnd[n, n - 1] == 0, {n, 1*^7}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 15.9120279
>
> 6.4116112

And now vectorized:

```
a = Range@1*^6;

Position[Log2@a, _Integer, {1}] // AbsoluteTiming // First

Position[BitAnd[a, a - 1], 0] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.4196025
>
> 0.0468001

Comment: If one still wants to take the logarithm route, `BitLength[]` is one function to look at...

Comment: @J.M. what are you thinking?

Comment: Aaah, I should have dug deeper in the documentation :-(. I knew about `Log10[]`, but didn't know there was a `Log2[]` as well. Thanks. (No need for Taylor here)

Comment: @stevenvh I don't think your question has been answered but I'm not sure it can be by anyone other than the *Mathematica* developers.  Nevertheless given the vastly superior performance of `BitAnd` it apparently isn't anything special. :^)

Comment: "what are you thinking?" - well, `BitLength[]` is effectively equivalent to `Log2[]`, so...

Comment: @J.M. please pardon my lack of understanding, but how do you figure that?  Isn't it rather like `Floor@Log2@x`?

Comment: I was thinking of a test along the lines of `n == 2^(BitLength[n] - 1)`

Comment: @J.M. ah... or `BitLength[n] != BitLength[n-1]`?

Comment: Yes, that too. :)

Answer (score 16):

There is in fact an easy test to determine if an integer is a power of $2$, thanks to [bit twiddling](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2):

```
hadamardMatrix[1] := {{1}}
hadamardMatrix[2] := {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}
hadamardMatrix[n_Integer /; Positive[n] && BitAnd[n, n - 1] == 0] := 
               KroneckerProduct[hadamardMatrix[2], hadamardMatrix[n/2]]
```

Comment: I was aware of the bit twiddling (I'm an electronics engineer and have low-level programmed lots of microcontrollers), but I thought the bit twiddling would be Mathematica's job, not mine :-). Still +1, thanks.

Comment: @steven, I know you're an EE; that's precisely why I brought bit twiddling up... ;)