# How do I numerically evaluate and plot the Fabius function?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, special-functions

The [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) is a well-known example in analysis of a non-analytic function that is infinitely differentiable. I want to be able to numerically evaluate the function for any real argument, as well as to plot it, just like the picture in Wikipedia:

[image]

I had found [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/VladimirReshetnikov/db8db5646dd197d0facec9c754dc43e3) by a Mr. [Reshetnikov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7288), but it seems to be only for fractions whose denominators are a power of two (a.k.a. *dyadic rationals*). Can that implementation be extended to compute, say the value at a non-dyadic rational like $2/3$, or a not exact number like $0.775$? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: another reference http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218832/how-to-compute-the-values-of-this-function-fabius-function

Comment: I should probably note that `SetPrecision[x, ∞]` will return a close dyadic rational approximant to an inexact number `x`.

Comment: Presently I have no time to try a solution but as the Fabius function is solution of a multiplicative delay differential equation --- for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ you must try to make your own solver with an Euler method and extend it.

Comment: I was wondering how to program the Fabius function then  I fell on that page http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218832/how-to-compute-the-values-of-this-function-fabius-function

Comment: https://gist.github.com/VladimirReshetnikov/cb205c1826e2fb78a785fa193f03eaba

Comment: This post of mine might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283519/19661

Comment: if you want a rough but simple approximation of the first lobe centered at zero, you could try $$\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 15):

Given $d\in\mathbb{N}_0$, the Taylor series about $i/2^d$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d$ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $S_d$ be the set of such Taylor series.

There exist unique polynomials $\text{pol}_0,\text{pol}_1,\ \dots\ ,\text{pol}_d$ of degree $0,1,\ \dots\ ,d$ and a function $c:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{R}\mapsto\{-1,0,1\}$, such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the following sum coincides with those Taylor series in $S_d$ whose point of expansion differs the least from $x$.

$$\sum_{i\ =\ 0}^d c(i, x)\ \text{pol}_i(\Lambda(2-2^{i+1}(x\bmod 2^{1-i})))$$

where $\Lambda$ is `HeavisideLambda`. The choice of $c$ is unique, except when $x=i/2^{d+1}$, where $i$ is an odd integer. In that case, there are 2 choices because the nearest Taylor series is not unique.

In my approximation, I use that sum of polynomials for computing values on $[0,2)$, and self-similarity for the extension to $\mathbb{R}$ and the derivatives.

#### **Ancient code, see update below:**

Young already linked the [Mathematics Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218832/how-to-compute-the-values-of-this-function-fabius-function) with my answer to this question, but I made some changes to the code. The first part which computes the values of $F(2^{-i})$ for $i=1,3,5,\dots$. I have got that to run much faster by avoiding additions of awkward rationals with huge GCDs. With help from [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), I found a "Mathematica-closed form" for the needed GCDs, which is much more efficient than the implicit GCD calls from addition of rationals.

```
Remove[d, recTable, fabs, pol, fabius, y, n, x]

d = 399;   (*polynomial degree of pieces; odd values make fabius[x] continuous*)

recTable = RecurrenceTable;
SetAttributes[{MultiplicativeOrder, pol}, Listable]

fabs = With[{F = Floor[d/2] + 1}, With[{gcd = 2^(F - DigitCount[F, 2, 1]) Times @@ (
         #^Quotient[F, (# - 1)/2]) &[Pick[#, # - 2 MultiplicativeOrder[4, #], 1] &[
           Prime[Range[3, Max[Floor[385/213 #], 4]]]][[;; #]] &[Count[MultiplicativeOrder[
             4, 2 # + 3] - #, 1] &[Range[F - 1]]]]},
  Reap[Fold[Append[#, Sow[Total[#]]] &[# #2] &,
   {Sow[gcd]}, With[{js = Map[# (2 # - 1) &, Range[-F, -2]],
   T = recTable[{y[n + 1] == 4 y[n] + 9, y[1] == 0}, y, {n, F}]},
   Table[Append[T[[i]]/js[[1 - i ;;]], 1], {i, F}]]]][[2, 1]]/FoldList[Times, 2 gcd,
   recTable[{y[n + 2] == 80 y[n + 1] - 1024 y[n], y[1] == 144, y[2] == 11520}, y, {n, F}]]]];
```

I also changed the form of polynomials, by putting GCDs outside parentheses to avoid repetitive, extensive GCD calculations when calling `fabius[x]` for different values of `x`.

```
Clear[pol]
Evaluate[Table[pol[r, x_], {r, d + 2}]] = With[{F = Floor[d/2]},
 With[{gcd = Prepend[Riffle[#, #2 #], 1][[;; d + 2]]}, 1/gcd
  MapIndexed[If[OddQ[First[#2]], x^-1, x^-2] Fold[(# + #2) x^2 &, 0, #] &,
   With[{p = Riffle[#2/2, #2, {2, d + 1, 2}], S = Join[Range[d, 1, -1], {1}],
    rat = Prepend[Riffle[#2, Ratios[#]/Most[#2]], 1][[;; d + 1]]},
     FoldList[rat[[#2]]/S[[-#2 ;; ;; 2]] If[OddQ[#2], Append[#/p[[#2]],
      2 fabs[[(#2 + 1)/2]] gcd[[#2]]], #/p[[#2]]] &, {}, Range[d + 1]]]]] &[
       Join[{1, 144}, Map[1/GCD @@ (2 fabs[[{3, # - 2, #}]]) &, Range[3, F + 1]]],
       NestList[4 # &, 2, Max[1, F]]]];
```

The changes to the definition part is hardly significant.

```
(T0 = Power[-1, #[[;; Ceiling[d/2 + 1]]]]; T1 = Mod[Most[#], 2];
 T2 = Power[2, #]; T3 = Power[2, Rest[#]]) &[Range[0, d + 1]];
Derivative[n_][fabius] = 2^(n (n + 1)/2) fabius[2^n #] &;
With[{prec = N[d/Log2[10] + 15], d2 = d + 2}, fabius[x_?NumericQ] :=
 With[{t = SetPrecision[#, Max[Precision[#], prec]] &[Mod[x, 2]]},
  With[{refs = Position[IntegerDigits[BitXor[BitShiftRight[#, 1], #] &[
   FromDigits[First[RealDigits[t, 2, d2, 0]], 2]], 2, d2], 1][[All, 1]]},
   (-1)^DigitCount[Floor[x, 2], 2, 1] If[
   refs =!= {}, Dot[T0[[Accumulate[Prepend[T1[[Most[refs]]], 1]]]],
  pol[refs, FoldList[(2 - #) #2 &, T2[[First[refs]]] t, T3[[Differences[refs]]]] - 1]], 0]]]]
```

There you go:

```
Plot[fabius[x], {x, 0, 24}, AspectRatio -> 1/12, ImageSize -> 800]
```

If `X` is uniformly distributed on the unit interval, the expected absolute error and the maximal absolute error of `fabius[X]` are both rationals. If you use `p = ∞` in the following code, you obtain their exact values. All local maxima of the error equal the maximal error, so the approximation is uniform in an absolute sense.

```
errors = With[{p = 10}, With[{sL = 2 Last[fabs] + Dot[
          Riffle[Table[pol[i + 1, N[1, p + (93 + 5 d)/28]],
           {i, 1, d + 1, 2}], Most[fabs]], Reverse[
            With[{q = Floor[d, 2] + 2}, FoldList[Times, 2^(-q),
             Reverse[recTable[{y[n + 1] == (n - q - 1) y[n]/2/
              (n - q), y[1] == -1/2/q}, y, {n, q - 1}]]]]]]},
               Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = ∞}, N[#, Precision[#]] &[
                If[OddQ[d], {2^(d + 1) Last[fabs], sL}, {2^(d + 1) sL, fabs[[-2]]}]]]]]
```

## **Update:**

I'm still using the sum at the top for the approximation, but some functionality is added, and now non-rational input is handled efficiently. Hence I wanted to provide this update:

The form of the polynomials is changed to:
$\ $`132809 + 3825 x^2 (2332 + 63 x^2 (266 + 15 x^2 (28 + 9 x^2)))`

instead of the `HornerForm`:
$\ $`132809 + x^2 (8919900 + x^2 (64099350 + x^2 (101209500 + 32531625 x^2)))`

because the asymptotic memory usage for the latter was very bad. Also, only coefficients for a finitely many (`memorizeDegree`) polynomial are memoized. Higher degree (`maxDegree`) polynomials are used, but only one/two of them is in memory at a given time.

I added an argument such that `fabius[x, p]` returns precision `p`. Each polynomial is computed to the needed precision only, unless `x` is rational and `ByteCount[x] < 3000`. In that case it's simply faster to use rational arithmetic. Such rational input evaluates much faster: E.g. if `maxDegree = 1119; memorizeDegree = 449;` then `Timing[fabius[4/3, 188888];]` and `Timing[fabius[E, 64888];]` are about the same.

`fabius[x, ∞]` returns the exact result, if possible (i.e., if `x` is dyadic with sufficiently small denominator). Otherwise, there's a warning.

The initialization part:

```
Remove[maxDegree, memorizeDegree, track, extraPrecision, fabius,
       polPrecs, polNext, polMove, polCoefs, polEval, logSizes, maxAbsErr]

maxDegree = 999; (* Nonnegativ integer *)
memorizeDegree = 449; (* Integer greater or equal 2; At 1139 my RAM is all used;
                         RAM use increases quadraticly *)
extraPrecision = 4; (* Nonnegativ real *)

polNext[k_, n_] := Module[{L = k},
  L[[1, All, 1]] /= Range[n - 2, 1, -2];
  L[[1]] = Reap[L[[2]] *= 2^n/Fold[Function[G, Sow[#/G]; G][
                 GCD @@ #] &[#2 {1, #}] &, 1/n, First[L]]][[2, 1]];
  If[EvenQ[n], AppendTo[L[[1]], {Fold[First[#2] + Last[#2] # &, 1/(n + 1),
       Transpose[{L[[1, All, 1]]/Range[n - 1, 3, -2], L[[1, All, 2]]}]]/(2^n - 1), 1}];
       (L[[1, -1]] *= #; L[[2]] *= #;) &[Denominator[L[[1, -1, 1]]]]]; L]


Dynamic[ToString[track/#] <> " %"] &[N[maxDegree/100, 3]]
polCoefs = Join[{{{}, ∞}, {{}, 1}, {{}, 2}}, FoldList[(track = #2;
                polNext[#, #2]) &, {{{1, 9}}, 144}, Range[3, memorizeDegree]]];
(polMove[cur_, n_, m_] := If[# >= m, polCoefs[[m + 2]], Fold[polNext,
                             cur, Range[n + 1, m]]]) &[memorizeDegree]
polEval[{L_, den_}, odd_, x_] := If[den === ∞, 0, Fold[(First[#2] +
                                    x^2 Last[#2] #) &, 1, L] If[odd, x, 1]/den]

With[{stability = Reap[Fold[With[{polNext = polMove[#, #2 - 1, #2]}, track = #2;
      Sow[polEval[polNext, OddQ[#2], 1`10]]; polNext] &, {}, Range[0, maxDegree]];][[2, 1]]},
 polPrecs = Join[{∞, ∞}, Rest[extraPrecision - (Accuracy /@ stability - 10)]];
 maxAbsErr = SetPrecision[If[maxDegree >= 3, Times @@ Power[stability[[-4 ;;]],
                          {-1, 4, -6, 4}], {1/2, 5/72, 1/288}[[maxDegree + 1]]], 6];
 logSizes = -Log10[stability];];
```

The actual function:

```
fabius::limit = "Maximal degree reached; Probably failed to return " <>
                "the requested precision; The absolute error is at most `1`";
fabius[x_?(#1 ∈ Reals &), p_?(#1 ∈ Reals || # === ∞ &)] := Module[{refs, prec,
        cac1 = {{{1, 9}}, 144}, cac2 = 3, mod = Mod[SetPrecision[x, ∞], 2],
        iMax, pMax = Identity, xs, noDyadic, d2 = maxDegree + 2, sum = 0, sign,
        doN = MatchQ[x, _Rational | _Integer] && ByteCount[x] < 3000},
noDyadic = If[doN && IntegerQ[#], # > maxDegree, True] &[Log2[Denominator[mod]]];
refs = Position[IntegerDigits[BitXor[BitShiftRight[#, 1], #] &[FromDigits[
                  First[RealDigits[mod, 2, d2, 0]], 2]], 2, d2], 1][[All, 1]];
prec = p + logSizes[[Max[Min[Ceiling[1 - Log2[Min[mod, 2 - mod]]], Length[logSizes]], 1]]];
sum = SetAccuracy[sum, prec + extraPrecision]; prec += polPrecs[[refs]];
If[refs === {} && noDyadic, Message[fabius::limit, maxAbsErr]];
If[refs === {}, sum = 0, iMax = First[FirstPosition[prec, _?Negative, {All + 1}, {1}]] - 1;
 refs = refs[[;; iMax]]; prec = (prec[[;; iMax]] /. If[p =!= ∞, ∞ -> MachinePrecision, {}]);
 If[Not[doN], pMax = Function[u, SetPrecision[#, u] &][Max[prec]]];
 xs = FoldList[pMax[(1 - #) #2 - 1] &, pMax[Last[#] mod - 1], Most[#]] &[
                BitShiftLeft[1, Append[Differences[refs], First[refs] - 1]]];
 If[Not[doN], xs = MapThread[SetPrecision, {xs, prec}]];
 sign = {1, -1}[[FoldList[BitXor, ThueMorse[Floor[x/2]], BitAnd[Most[refs] - 1, 1]] + 1]];
 MapThread[(sum += #2 polEval[cac1 = polMove[cac1, cac2, cac2 = #], OddQ[#], #3]; 0) &,
  {refs - 2, sign, xs}]; If[noDyadic && iMax === All, Message[fabius::limit, maxAbsErr]];];
 (Remove[refs, prec, cac1, cac2, xs, pMax, mod, sign, sum, noDyadic, iMax, d2, doN];
  If[#2 && # != 0, SetPrecision[#, Min[Log10[Abs[#]] - Log10[maxAbsErr], Precision[#]]], #]
  ) &[sum, noDyadic]]
```

I'm not sure whether I should just remove the ancient code.

Answer (score 9):

My version:

```
ClearAll[fabius];

fabius::usage = "fabius[x] gives the value of the Fabius function F(x) for a non-negative real argument x.";
fabius::nnreal = "Argument `1` should be a non-negative real number.";

Macros`SetArgumentCount[fabius, 1];
SyntaxInformation[fabius] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
Attributes[fabius] = {NumericFunction, Listable};

fabius[x : Underflow[] | Overflow[] | _DirectedInfinity] :=
(Message[fabius::nnreal, x]; Undefined);
fabius[x_] /; Im[x] != 0 || Re[x] < 0 := (Message[fabius::nnreal, x]; Undefined);

Module[{t, c, d, f},
  t[0] = 1; t[n_] := t[n] = (-1)^n t[Quotient[n, 2]];
  c[0] = 1; c[n_] := c[n] = Sum[c[n - m]/(2 m + 1)!, {m, n}]/(4^n - 1);
  d[n_] := d[n] = Sum[c[m]/(n - 2 m)!, {m, 0, n/2}]/2^(n (n + 1)/2);
  f[x_, p_] := f[x, p] = Module[{z = x, n, s, y = 0},
     While[z > 0,
       n = -Floor[Log2[z]]; z -= 2^-n;
       s = d[n] + Sum[d[n - m] 2^(m (m + 1)/2) z^m/m!, {m, n}]; y = s - y;
       If[p < Infinity && Abs[s/y] < 10^-p, Break[]]];
     SetPrecision[Abs[y], p]];

  fabius[x_] /; ExactNumberQ[x] && IntegerQ[Log2[Denominator[x]]] && 0 <= x <= 2 :=
  f[x, Infinity];
  fabius[x_] /; NumericQ[x] && x > 2 := fabius[Mod[x, 2]] t[Quotient[x, 2]];
  fabius[x_] /; NumericQ[x] && Im[x] == 0 && Re[x] >= 0 && Precision[x] < Infinity :=
  f[Rationalize[x, 0], Precision[x]];
  N[fabius[x_], {p_, _}] /; NumericQ[x] && Im[x] == 0 && Re[x] >= 0 := f[x, p];
  Derivative[n_][fabius][x_] := 2^(n (n + 1)/2) fabius[2^n x]];
```

Examples:

```
fabius[5/16]
(* 305857/2073600 *)

fabius[2/3]
(* fabius[2/3] *)

N[%, 60]
(* 0.819834885198518093044266564068975877132092199918258367435956 *)

fabius[0.775]
(* 0.953056 *)
```

Comment: `N[fabius[Pi], 5]` outputs `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.` few times and 0.99362.

Comment: I updated the answer to extend the function domain to all non-negative reals.

Comment: A paper explaining some background for this algorithm: J. Arias de Reyna, [Arithmetic of the Fabius Function](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/s51/s51.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly optimized version of Vladimir's code (which is an implementation of Rvachëv's method), based on results derived by Arias de Reyna in these [two](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442) [notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06487). (See also [this related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261649).)

The two main ingredients in the following code are the optimized direct generation of the coefficients `d` in Vladimir's code (called `ariasD[]` in the implementation below), using Arias's recurrence, and the reformulation of the evaluation of the underlying approximating polynomials to Horner form. In addition, as I already noted in a comment above, `SetPrecision[x, ∞]` is more appropriate to use here than `Rationalize[x, 0]` for converting inexact arguments, since it directly generates the nearest dyadic rational (see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84234) as well).

```
FabiusF::usage =
"FabiusF[x] gives the value of the Fabius function F(x) for a non-negative real argument x.";
Macros`SetArgumentCount[FabiusF, 1];
SyntaxInformation[FabiusF] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
SetAttributes[FabiusF, {NumericFunction, Listable}];

Derivative[n_Integer][FabiusF] := 2^(n (n + 1)/2) FabiusF[2^n #] &

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13245 *)
powerOfTwoQ[n_] := IntegerQ[n] && BitAnd[n, n - 1] == 0

FabiusF[Infinity] = Interval[{-1, 1}];
FabiusF[x_?NumberQ] /; If[0 <= Re[x] && Im[x] == 0,
                          powerOfTwoQ[Denominator[x]], 
                          Message[FabiusF::realnn, x]; False] := iFabiusF[x]

ariasD[0] = 1;
ariasD[n_Integer?Positive] := ariasD[n] = 
     Sum[2^((k (k - 1) - n (n - 1))/2) ariasD[k]/(n - k + 1)!, {k, 0, n - 1}]/(2^n - 1);

tri[x_] := Piecewise[{{2 - x, x > 1}}, x]

iFabiusF[x_] := Module[{prec = Precision[x], s = 1, y = 0, z = SetPrecision[x, Infinity],
                        n, p, q, tol, w},
       z = If[0 <= z <= 2, tri[z],
              q = Quotient[z, 2];
              (* can replace ThueMorse[] with the implementation
                 in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89351 *)
              If[ThueMorse[q] == 1, s = -1]; tri[z - 2 q]];
       tol = 10^(-prec);
       While[z > 0, n = -Floor[RealExponent[z, 2]]; p = 2^n; z -= 1/p; w = 1;
             Do[w = ariasD[m] + p z w/(n - m + 1); p /= 2, {m, n}];
             y = w - y;
             If[Abs[w] < Abs[y] tol, Break[]]];
       SetPrecision[s Abs[y], prec]]
```

Some examples:

```
FabiusF[Range[0, 10]]
   {0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0}

Table[{x, FabiusF[x]}, {x, {1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 3/8, 5/8}}]
   {{1/2, 1/2}, {1/4, 5/72}, {3/4, 67/72}, {1/8, 1/288}, {3/8, 73/288}, {5/8, 215/288}}

{FabiusF[2/3], N[FabiusF[2/3], 30]}
   {FabiusF[2/3], 0.819834885198518093044266564069}

{FabiusF[π], N[FabiusF[π], 30]}
   {FabiusF[π], -0.993623885966442415174972734961}
```

and finally, a plot, just like what the OP asked for:

```
Plot[FabiusF[x], {x, 0, 24}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Fabius function plot]

As a bonus:

```
ParametricPlot[{FabiusF[t], FabiusF'[t]}, {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: a Fabius loop]