# Speed up the generation of large Hadamard matrices

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I need to generate a Hadamard matrix with dimensions of $4096$, but it seems *Mathematica* is much slower than MATLAB when generating such matrices.

This program

```
(MatrixPlot @ HadamardMatrix[4096]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

cost about **36** seconds on my computer to finish. While for MATLAB,

```
 H = hadamard(4096); imshow(H)
```

cost about **0.7** seconds.

I tested the pure process of generating the `H` matrix. The code is listed below.

*Mathematica* cost **20** seconds:

```
HadamardMatrix[4096, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision] // AbsoluteTiming
```

MATLAB cost **0.12** second:

```
hadamard(4096)
```

I was wondering if there is any method to increase the speed or efficiency of *Mathematica* on this problem?

Jim has provided a way of changing the Method:

```
HadamardMatrix[4096, Method -> "BitComplement"] // AbsoluteTiming
HadamardMatrix[4096, Method -> "Sequency"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It improves the speed a little bit, but still much slower than MATLAB
[image]

Comment: While I don’t  think that this is the cause of the slow down, you still shouldn’t include the plotting function in your timing. Secondarily, consider also that the Hadamard matrix produced by Mathematica is normalized by a factor of $1/\sqrt{n}$, whereas Matlab produces a matrix of $\pm 1$. Having said that, if the timing in both systems is accurate, the difference is very large indeed.

Comment: Does using `HadamardMatrix[4096, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]` alter the timing significantly? (I’m on mobile and can’t test it myself).

Comment: Also, *Mathematica* produces two flavors:  `Method->"BitComplement"` and `Method->"Sequency"`.  The former is much faster.  Which does *Matlab* produce?

Comment: @MarcoB，@JimB，It should be right that it should be blamed on the Sqrt[n] here. Method->"BitComplement" and Method->"Sequency" can improve this problem a little bit. However,it seems WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision cann't improve the behavoir too much. I' wondering whether there is a solution to force the internal calculation to use machine precision numbers, just as Matlab does.

Comment: @MarcoB change the working precision is not a very effective way. It still uses an awfully long time to produce the result.

Comment: I guess I have to use matlink to let matlab do this step and switch back to mathematica for other things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MATLAB matrix is similar to the `BitComplement` type. Avoiding `HadamardMatrix` makes the construction slightly faster.

```
r1 = Nest[ArrayFlatten[{{#, #}, {#, -#}}] &, {{1}}, Log2[4096]]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Sign[HadamardMatrix[4096, Method -> "BitComplement",
                         WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]]; // AbsoluteTiming
r1 === r2
```

> {0.14940275, Null}
>   {0.36388055, Null}
>   True

Regarding the creation of an image, you should not use `MatrixPlot`. It constructs a `Graphics` which is awfully slow. Rather you can create an `Image`

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 r1 = Nest[ArrayFlatten[{{#, #}, {#, -#}}] &, {{1}}, Log2[4096]];
 Image[r1]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's much faster! Thanks

Comment: This is a little bit faster: `Nest[KroneckerProduct[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}, #] &, {{1}}, BitLength[4096] - 1]`

Answer (score 8):

Some spelunking of the code for `HadamardMatrix[]` reveals why it is so slow with the option setting `Method -> "Sequency"`. (Coolwater's answer already shows the method corresponding to `Method -> "BitComplement"`).

Altho the function is internally using a `CompiledFunction[]` for the purpose, it is slow because of repeated calls to `IntegerDigits[]`. I have thus reorganized the algorithm being used in the code that follows:

```
hadmat[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: ∞] /; BitAnd[n, n - 1] == 0 := 
   With[{bits = IntegerDigits[Range[0, n - 1], 2, BitLength[n] - 1]},
        ((-1)^(ListCorrelate[{{1, 1}}, Reverse[bits, 2], 1, {0}].Transpose[bits]))/
        Sqrt[N[n, prec]]]
```

where I have used the [classical bit-twiddling test for a power of 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13245).

Even if it is uncompiled, `hadmat[]` handily outperforms the built-in:

```
AbsoluteTiming[t1 = hadmat[4096];]
   {4.54179, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[t2 = HadamardMatrix[4096];]
   {37.9819, Null}

t1 === t2
   True
```

(It should perhaps be emphasized that the two method settings for `HadamardMatrix[]` give different sets of matrices, but both produce matrices with the Hadamard property.)

---

For giggles, I wrote a compiled routine for generating the Hadamard matrix:

```
hmc = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {l, _Integer}},
              With[{bits = Table[IntegerDigits[k - 1, 2, l], {k, n}]},
                   (-1)^(bits.Table[Switch[l - j - k + 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, _, 0],
                                           {j, l}, {k, l}].Transpose[bits])]];

hadm2[n_Integer?Positive, prec_: ∞] /; BitAnd[n, n - 1] == 0 := 
    hmc[n, BitLength[n] - 1]/Sqrt[N[n, prec]]
```

where convolution is replaced with multiplication by an antitriangular matrix. As expected, this method is slower than the method based on `ListCorrelate[]`, but is still faster than the built-in.